# Create every time newly excel file and transfer database value

Tags: ssis

How can I create a new Excel file and transfer all the data from the database using SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "Export Data" from SQL Server Management Studio.

Right click the database, choose Tasks -> Export Data & follow the wizard, works really well for simple exports in my experience.

You can save the SSIS it creates if you need to make any mods.